# MySQL Date -> Into EuroDate

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

** Hi there **
How do i get eurodate from mysql date in ci, to work....
Can't igure it out - please help

Want to get date YY-mm- dd -> dd-mm-yy

Thanx in advance

Comment: "EuroDate" is EN 28601, same as ISO 8601. CCYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2):

```
$timeval = date_create_from_format('y-m-d', $mysql_date);
$eurodate = date('d-m-y', $timeval);
```

docs for these functions are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [here](http://php.net/date), respectively

Or, if you're wanting to get a euro-format date directly out of mysql, then

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%y-%m-%d') FROM ...
```

docs for this function are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).